# Rails font awesome helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, font-awesome

I'm replacing .pngs in my app with font awesome. I'm using the rails helper method. I'm curious why this works:

```
<%= fa_icon('file-pdf-o', size:'2em') %>
```

While this doesn't

```
<%= fa_icon('file-pdf-o', font-size:'2em') %>
```

I know I should be doing this in the CSS. But just curious what I'm doing wrong with the syntax here and how I can make it work.

Comment: Is this a helper that you wrote or is it included in some gem?

Comment: @H-man here's the gem that I used https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails. Dope profile pic btw.

Comment: Ha.. thanks. It fits Monday mood perfectly. I don't think `size: '2em'` works as well.

Comment: Did you try this `<%= fa_icon('file-pdf-o', font: { size: '2em' }) %>`

Comment: You have access to the following options: `text`, `class`, `right`

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Thanks for your answer. Does not work however.

Comment: Take a look at the html output those lines produce and compare it with the examples in the source code and you should be able to see exactly what is happening.

Comment: @H-man You can use other options too.

Comment: `font-size` should be throwing a syntax error because it would be trying to parse the ruby of `font - size` but neither of those would actually set a size attribute.

Answer (score 0):

`fa_icon` is just a helper method that converts your simple syntax into html. Take a look at the code for it from the [projects github page](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails/blob/master/app/helpers/font_awesome/rails/icon_helper.rb):

```
# Creates an icon tag given an icon name and possible icon
# modifiers.
#
# Examples
#
# fa_icon "camera-retro"
# # => <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>
#
# fa_icon "camera-retro", text: "Take a photo"
# # => <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> Take a photo
# fa_icon "chevron-right", text: "Get started", right: true
# # => Get started <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
#
# fa_icon "camera-retro 2x"
# # => <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x"></i>
# fa_icon ["camera-retro", "4x"]
# # => <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-4x"></i>
# fa_icon "spinner spin lg"
# # => <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-lg">
#
# fa_icon "quote-left 4x", class: "pull-left"
# # => <i class="fa fa-quote-left fa-4x pull-left"></i>
#
# fa_icon "user", data: { id: 123 }
# # => <i class="fa fa-user" data-id="123"></i>
#
# content_tag(:li, fa_icon("check li", text: "Bulleted list item"))
# # => <li><i class="fa fa-check fa-li"></i> Bulleted list item</li>
def fa_icon(names = "flag", options = {})
  classes = ["fa"]
  classes.concat Private.icon_names(names)
  classes.concat Array(options.delete(:class))
  text = options.delete(:text)
  right_icon = options.delete(:right)
  icon = content_tag(:i, nil, options.merge(:class => classes))
  Private.icon_join(icon, text, right_icon)
end
```

This should help you see what your code is doing.